# Yii2 - How to add custom error messages on input fields

Tags: validation, label, message, yii2, rules

In my database I named 'password' as 'password_hash' so automatically I'd get 'password_hash' in my error message, even tho I changed the label to 'Current password'.

Example:

[image]

**What I want is:**

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**So basically all I did was add**

```
'message' => 'Current password cannot be blank.'
```

**to my rules.**

Make sure you seperate the correct rules, so you don't get that message on multiple fields, where it doesn't make sense. Also make sure you add it on the `'required'` rule, unless you want that message to show when it's another rule..

I hope this helped you guys, as I spent a bit too much time searching for it.

Comment: The real answer! Even that the first one could be valid in some cases.

Comment: i read please provide proper example .people come here to copy code sample.

Answer (score 7):

From what you described it seems that you changed the label displayed in the form, not attribute label.

No need to duplicate error message and separate attributes to different rules, for most of the cases changing the attribute label in `attributeLabels()` method is enough.

That way if you change the language of application, it will show correct error message.

In your model:

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        ...
        'password_hash' => 'Current password',
    ];
}
```

All default validators take the label of attribute from this section, if it's not defined it will be transformed to "Password Hash".

Comment: Correct indeed, It was my fault for using the password as example. I was actually talking in general, if you'd still like to keep 1 form message to be different than the others, you could do it like the 'message' way.